# Inner join query in PHP tell me all others join query like that?

Tags: php, sql

this code is correct or not for inner join
how i improve this PHP code if any more suggestions for all type of join query comments

```
<?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','sql_joins');
        $sql = "select department.depname , employee.Name From employee INNER JOIN department ON department.Empid = employee.Empid"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            ?> 
        <table style="border:1px solid #666;"> 
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>Depname</td> 
        </tr> 
                <?php 
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
                {

        while($run=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                    <tr > 
                    <td style="border:1px solid #666;"> <?php echo $run["Name"]; ?></td> 
                    <td style="border:1px solid #666;"> <?php echo $run["depname"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }?> 
            </table> 
            <?php 
        }else{ 
            echo "not"; 
        } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong in your code, such as:

- Your SQL query is wrong, plus you didn't make use of `INNER JOIN` in your query. Your query should be like this:

  ```
  SELECT department.depname , employee.Name 
  FROM employee 
  INNER JOIN department ON department.Empid = employee.Empid
  ```
- Instead of `if($result){ ...`, make use of [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) function in the `if` condition to check how many rows are retrieved from the `SELECT` operation.

  ```
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){ ...
  ```
- Your HTML table structure is wrong, it should be like this:

  ```
  <table style="border:1px solid #666;"> 
      <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>Depname</td> 
      </tr>
      <?php 
      while($run=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
      ...
  ```